# angular ngRoute Js TypeError: Cannot read property 'ID_of_element' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

i have this error

```
angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property '103' of undefined
```

103 is an  ID of my element

and my code is app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute','ngAnimate']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "home.html"
    }).
  when("/quatre/:id",{
    templateUrl:'quatre.html',controller:'ViewIdInformation'}).
  when("/404", {
        templateUrl : "404.html"
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo:'/404'
    });
});

app.controller('ViewIdInformation',['$scope','$routeParams',function($scope,$routeParams){
    $scope.x = $scope.myWelcome[$routeParams.id];
}]);
```

and the code of my page  quatre.html is like this

```
{{x.id}}
```

but i have the same problem please any help.

Comment: Your `$scope.myWelcome` is not defined. `$routeParams.id` seems like having value `103`. Ring any bells?

Answer (score 0):

thank you stackoverflow i find the solution is like this

```
app.controller('ViewIdInformation',['$scope','$routeParams',function($scope,$routeParams){

                            $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
```